# Edge Animate: variable created on click in edgeActions.js but want to reference it in external js file

Tags: jquery, adobe-edge

I created a variable on-click in edgeActions.js but want to reference it in external js file. This is where I am at so far:

In my edgeActions.js I st a variable on compositionReady and then use it when I click on the symbol: questionMarkR1. This works fine.. the problem is that I don't know how to reference the variable in my external js file. This first code is working from the edgeActions.js:

```
Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "document", "compositionReady", function(sym, e) {


         sym.setVariable("questionAsked", false); // sets the initial value

      });


 Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${_questionMarkR1}", "click", function(sym, e) {


         var questionAsked = sym.getVariable("questionAsked");

         alert(questionAsked);


         if (questionAsked)// if true 
         {
         sym.$("checkButton2").removeClass( "hidden" );
         sym.$("popUp").removeClass( "hidden" );


         }
         else  //if false
         {


         sym.$("pic2a").removeClass( "hidden" );
         sym.$("pic2b").removeClass( "hidden" );
         sym.$("pic2c").removeClass( "hidden" );
         sym.$("pic2d").removeClass( "hidden" );

         sym.$("closeBox").removeClass( "hidden" );
         }

      });
```

This next part doesn't work because I don't know how to reference the variable correctly. This is what I have tried and it doesn't work:

```
 var questionAsked = sym.getComposition().getStage().getVariable("questionAsked");


 alert(questionAsked);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
 var comp = AdobeEdge.getComposition("EDGE-606063631"); // replace "EDGE-606063631" with your comp id, you can find in the .html file

 var stage = comp.getStage();

 var questionAsked = stage.getVariable("questionAsked");

 alert(questionAsked);
```